# BasicHttpBinding Error - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Problem is not calling the wcf function using basichttpBinding and showing an error.
No host to route error comes up on Visual Studio.

**Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (No route to host)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using HelloWorld_App4.localhost;

namespace HelloWorld_App4
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.

            localhost.Service1 obj = new localhost.Service1();

            obj.GetData(32, true);

            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What license have you got?
If you only have the Indie license you wont be allowed to access web/wcf services and have to rely on rest services.

I found that out the hard way but then just switched ot using ASP.Net Web API to create my services. Simple and much cheaper that to buy the business license.